# Call it log, History, Events, Activity, etc

Tags: history, user-communication

I have an application, where everything is logged so that a user, later on, can look through all activity. It is just a small part of app. **But what do I call this "log" so that even a child would understand what it's there for**, the best I came up with was "*What's happened..*"

Any suggestions?

Cheers!

Comment: Is this for a child?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Facebook, it's called the [Activity Log](https://www.facebook.com/help/437430672945092), and you can "View Activity Log" from your Facebook page.

On GNOME, it's called the [Activity Journal](https://launchpad.net/gnome-activity-journal).

A log or journal is normally a known word to a native English speaker, and the prefix activity should suffice for a native to properly contextualise it.

Do you have a specific user population in mind? If so, you should document it with more details in your question.

Comment: The user could be an experienced IT-manager or a corner shop owner with little to no experience with the terms we use in the digital world.

Answer (score 0):

We usually like naming things based on the language used by our users. As we're doing user research we pay close attention to the words and phrases they use. There are usually other words that don't come up naturally during the session that we might ask about directly: Shopping Cart, Reporting, etc.

If your app is for general use, you can still talk with likely users. Or just pick a common word (some competitive research can help here).